# How to fire a method of UI Activity from a extended component

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onAnimationEnd() {
    super.onAnimationEnd();
}
```

This overriden method of a view triggers ok but how can i fire a method of UI from this method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is how i done it:

```
@Override
protected void onAnimationEnd() {
    super.onAnimationEnd();
    MainActivity.handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

I have a static handler object in MainActivity which looks for incoming messages. That is all but i want to know if there is a better aproach?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run something on the UI Thread? You can call the `runOnUiThread` method within the `Activity`, and pass a `Runnable` through with it, which will execute the code within on the Ui Thread.

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       // Do something on the UI Thread
    }
  });
```

You have to bare in mind that the `runOnUiThread` will switch the code to the Ui Thread, so make sure you don't do any longer operations once you have switched. You also have to bare in mind that you are switching Threads, and so you cannot guarantee that the code inside the `runOnUiThread` method will run before anything you call after it.

So in your example you would use:

```
@Override
protected void onAnimationEnd() {
    super.onAnimationEnd();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           // Do something on the UI Thread
        }
    });
    // continue with non-UI Thread stuff
}
```

Comment: I have a MainActivity which uses extended viewflipper classes, when this event triggered in an overriden method of viewflipper. I want a method of MainActivity to run.